# Loss not changing and accuracy remains 0 after calling fit()

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, normalization, tf.keras

I'm new to keras and tensorflow, I have a model that I am trying to train where the loss does not change after epoch #1.

my data is the sequence of numbers which I want NN to learn and predict the next number:

```
data[10:15]
Out[3]: 
array([[30, 36, 28, 25, 30, 35],
       [36, 28, 25, 30, 35, 28],
       [28, 25, 30, 35, 28, 29],
       [25, 30, 35, 28, 29, 25],
       [30, 35, 28, 29, 25, 38]])
```

For example I want *[30, 36, 28, 25, 30]* to be my input and *35* to be my output.

and this is my very simple code and NN:
[I normalized all my data using StandardScaler() but it didn't change.]

```
    data = gen_train_data()

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

    X_train_full, X_test, y_train_full, y_test = train_test_split(data[:, 0:5], data[:, 5])
    X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train_full, y_train_full)

    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="elu", kernel_initializer="he_normal"))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax"))

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])

    early_stopping_cb = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        epochs=16, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid),
                        callbacks=[early_stopping_cb])

    mse_test = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

and this is my console after running code above:

```
Epoch 1/16
 1/26 [>.............................] - ETA: 57s - loss: 3.2932 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
26/26 [==============================] - 3s 23ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/16
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/16
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/16
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/16
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/16
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/16
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/16
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/16
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/16
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/16
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 2.0375 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.2258 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
12/12 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1.7458 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

and the prediction is 1 for **all inputs**

```
model.predict(X_test[:5])
Out[2]: 
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)
```

I tried everything (activation functions, learning rates, more/less hidden layers, ...), nothing changes the output.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me

Comment: *and the prediction is 1 for all inputs*, because you are using softmax with one neuron. What would you expect for the output rather than 1? Also accuracy is not a valid metric for regression. So relying on accuracy in this case is meaningless.

Comment: `softmax` is a squashing function whose range is 0 to 1. You should
   rather be using "linear" activation in the last layer.

Comment: You can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) tutorial on how to implement regression model from scratch. Thanks!